# Scrapy trying to get URL's of videos but I always get same url for different videos

Tags: python, html, scrapy, css-selectors

[image: HTML CODE of the website]

That's the HTML code for who cannot read from image

```
</div>              <div id="rezults_kont"><div class="rezult_item row" style="border-bottom:1px solid #ddd;margin-bottom:6px;">    <div class="col-xs-4 col-xs-6" style="text-align:right;padding-left:0px;padding-right:5px;"><video id="vid_degiske_01-01_1" class="vid vid_81x54" muted  ><source src="/vidz_proc/0001/degiske/01-01_cr_0.1.mp4" /></video><video id="vid_degiske_01-02_2" class="vid vid_81x54" muted  ><source src="/vidz_proc/0001/degiske/01-02_cr_0.1.mp4" /></video><video id="vid_degiske_01-03_3" class="vid vid_81x54" muted  ><source src="/vidz_proc/0001/degiske/01-03_cr_0.1.mp4" /></video></div>
    <a href="/tr/Ben?d=0001" style="color:#000;">
             <div class="col-md-8 col-xs-6 result_item_to_detail" id="s_0001">  <h3 style="position:relative;top:-15px;margin-bottom:-15px;">Ben</h3><span class="rezult_item_en_span">I, Me</span> </div></a></div><div class="rezult_item row" style="border-bottom:1px solid #ddd;margin-bottom:6px;">   <div class="col-xs-4 col-xs-6" style="text-align:right;padding-left:0px;padding-right:5px;"><video id="vid_degiske_02-01_1" class="vid vid_81x54" muted  ><source src="/vidz_proc/0002/degiske/02-01_cr_0.1.mp4" /></video><video id="vid_degiske_02-02_2" class="vid vid_81x54" muted  ><source src="/vidz_proc/0002/degiske/02-02_cr_0.1.mp4" /></video></div>
    <a href="/tr/O?d=0002" style="color:#000;">
             <div class="col-md-8 col-xs-6 result_item_to_detail" id="s_0002">  <h3 style="position:relative;top:-15px;margin-bottom:-15px;">O</h3><span class="rezult_item_en_span">He, She, It, That</span>   </div></a></div><div class="rezult_item row" style="border-bottom:1px solid #ddd;margin-bottom:6px;">   <div class="col-xs-4 col-xs-6" style="text-align:right;padding-left:0px;padding-right:5px;"><video id="vid_degiske_03-01_1" class="vid vid_81x54" muted  ><source src="/vidz_proc/0003/degiske/03-01_cr_0.1.mp4" /></video><video id="vid_degiske_03-02_2" class="vid vid_81x54" muted  ><source src="/vidz_proc/0003/degiske/03-02_cr_0.1.mp4" /></video></div>
    <a href="/tr/Sen?d=0003" style="color:#000;">
             <div class="col-md-8 col-xs-6 result_item_to_detail" id="s_0003">  <h3 style="position:relative;top:-15px;margin-bottom:-15px;">Sen</h3><span class="rezult_item_en_span">You</span>   </div></a></div><div class="rezult_item row" style="border-bottom:1px solid #ddd;margin-bottom:6px;">   <div class="col-xs-4 col-xs-6" style="text-align:right;padding-left:0px;padding-right:5px;"><video id="vid_degiske_04-01_1" class="vid vid_81x54" muted  ><source src="/vidz_proc/0004/degiske/04-01_cr_0.1.mp4" /></video><video id="vid_degiske_04-02_2" class="vid vid_81x54" muted  ><source src="/vidz_proc/0004/degiske/04-02_cr_0.1.mp4" /></video></div>
    <a href="/tr/Bu?d=0004" style="color:#000;">
             <div class="col-md-8 col-xs-6 result_item_to_detail" id="s_0004">  <h3 style="position:relative;top:-15px;margin-bottom:-15px;">Bu</h3><span class="rezult_item_en_span">This</span>   </div></a></div><div class="rezult_item row" style="border-bottom:1px solid #ddd;margin-bottom:6px;">   <div class="col-xs-4 col-xs-6" style="text-align:right;padding-left:0px;padding-right:5px;"><video id="vid_degiske_05-01_1" class="vid vid_81x54" muted  ><source src="/vidz_proc/0005/degiske/05-01_cr_0.1.mp4" /></video><video id="vid_degiske_05-02_2" class="vid vid_81x54" muted  ><source src="/vidz_proc/0005/degiske/05-02_cr_0.1.mp4" /></video><video id="vid_degiske_05-05_3" class="vid vid_81x54" muted  ><source src="/vidz_proc/0005/degiske/05-05_cr_0.1.mp4" /></video><br>1 adet daha değişkesi var. </div>
    <a href="/tr/Gitmek?d=0005" style="color:#000;">
             <div class="col-md-8 col-xs-6 result_item_to_detail" id="s_0005">  <h3 style="position:relative;top:-15px;margin-bottom:-15px;">Gitmek</h3><span class="rezult_item_en_span">To go, To leave, Take leave, Get off, To depart, To take off, To arrive, To lose money</span> </div></a></div><div class="rezult_item row" style="border-bottom:1px solid #ddd;margin-bottom:6px;">   <div class="col-xs-4 col-xs-6" style="text-align:right;padding-left:0px;padding-right:5px;"><video id="vid_degiske_06-01_1" class="vid vid_81x54" muted  ><source src="/vidz_proc/0006/degiske/06-01_cr_0.1.mp4" /></video></div>
```

Hi,
I am trying to get url of videos for different words with this code `response.css('.rezult_item.row source').xpath("@src").extract_first()`.

For example, Word is "Ben" and url of that word is "/vidz_proc/0001/degiske/01-01_cr_0.1.mp4". However, when I skipped into other word like "O" url is not change, it is still "/vidz_proc/0001/degiske/01-01_cr_0.1.mp4" but it should be "/vidz_proc/0002/degiske/02-02_cr_0.1.mp4". I couldn't figure out what should I change in my code.

That's the whole parse function

```
 def parse(self, response):
     items = TidtutorialItem()

     all_div_kelimeler = response.css(".col-md-8.col-xs-6.result_item_to_detail")

     

     all_div_pagelink = response.css(".rezult_item.row")

     #all_div_url = response.css(".col-lg-4.col-md-3.inZero")
     all_div_url = response.css(".rezult_item.row")
     print(all_div_url)
     index = 0

     while (index < len(all_div_kelimeler)):


         kelime = all_div_kelimeler[index].css('.col-md-8.col-xs-6.result_item_to_detail h3::text').extract()

        
         items['Kelime'] = kelime



         pagelink = 'http://...' + all_div_pagelink[index].css('.rezult_item.row a').xpath("@href").extract_first()
         items['Page_Link'] = pagelink

         url =  '...'+ response.css('.rezult_item.row source').xpath("@src").extract_first()
         items['URL'] = url

         yield items
         index +=1

         next_page = '...' +str(TidSpider.page_number)

         if TidSpider.page_number < 3:

             TidSpider.page_number += 1
      
             yield response.follow(next_page,callback= self.parse)
```

Comment: Please add the relevant code to your question

Comment: I added the code

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Is everything okay for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this part of your code `url =  '...'+ response.css('.rezult_item.row source').xpath("@src").extract_first()` you refer to the same part in the html in your loop, so it makes sense you always get the same item. You can try to do it like this:

```
all_div_kelimeler[index].css('.rezult_item.row source').xpath("@src").extract_first()
```

This way you will only look in the section under 'all_div_kelimeler[index]' instead of in the whole response object.

Comment: Thanks, that solved the problem. I just used all_div_pagelink[index].css('.rezult_item.row source').xpath("@src").extract_first() instead of all_div_kelimeler[index].....